# Insert into with Cursor.executemany and a Python list

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Can someone please explain to me what is wrong with this code?  I get the "parameters are of unsupported type" error.  Is it not possible to feed a list into cursor.executemany?  The type of the column is float not null.

```
random_numbers = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
]

cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO Table (Column) VALUES (?)', random_numbers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for `cursor.executemany` must be a sequence of *tuples*:

```py
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO Table (Column) VALUES (?)', 
                   [(n,) for n in random_numbers])
```

This is a logical extension of `cursor.execute` requiring a single `tuple` for the values argument.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it but I still get an error when I run this - "int object is not iterable"

Comment: My bad, `tuple(n)` only works if `n` is an iterable.  The new version should work.

Comment: Ah, amazing, thank you.  And I checked - the trailing comma that you put after the first n is required - I did read something about why but didn't really understand so I'll go over it again.  Thanks very much.

Comment: The trailing comma is what creates a tuple.

Comment: `import random
random_numbers.clear()
random_numbers = []
for i in range(1000):
    random_numbers.append((random.randint(10,25),))

cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO Pressure VALUES (?)',
                  random_numbers)`

I'm very pleased to say that this also worked!